# Importing 16:9 into 2:1 while maintaining the original aspect ratio

Tags: video

I am importing a 16:9 video (1920x1080) into a 2:1 edit (2048x1024) and every time I do, the imported video's aspect ratio changes a little making it look stretched. I can correct by adjusting the scale, but then that seems create blocking artifacts in the final render no matter what bitrate I use. Is there a way to import and keep the 16:9 ratio without having to adjust the scale?

Background.  In my case I am using Blender to render Virtual Reality video.  Been using it successfully for over a year with great results. I simply import the left and right eyes into blender (which are two perfectly round fisheye videos) edit and render. I capture content in 16:9 video but in order to use a new VR streaming tool, I need a 2:1 aspect ratio.

Much appreciated.

Source
[image]

Output
[image]

Comment: So basically you're looking to pad the original video with black (or whatever colour you prefer) borders on the sides to a 2:1 aspect ratio?

Comment: Have you tried texturing a plane with the 16:9 video and "filming" that from a camera, setting your output dimensions to the 2:1 ratio?  Use the "Generated" mapping option to see how that goes first.  Scale the plane's X/Y axis separately.  You might avoid the artifacts that way.   I've made quite dramatic changes to imported videos using this method and so far without hassles.

Comment: I added a sample output video (side by side fisheye) and a sample input (single fisheye). The output is 2048x1024 and the input is 1920x1080.  @Edgel3D That sounds very complicated. I have been scaling the X/Y axis separately and while it looks good in Blender, the final render has blocking artifacts.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LX_c8tmUnOg&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4&index=7

Comment: In the VSE under Strip Input you can enable image offset - this keeps the original resolution and allows you to position the strip within the final video.

Comment: Filming off a 2D plane is far simpler than using the VSE with effects strips etc.  Scaling can be tested with the convenience of WYSIWYG when you render using "OpenGL".  It's a lot faster too.  

If it turns out you cannot solve this and haven't tried or unable to set my suggestion up, leave a comment here and I'll make a Blender file up for you to use.  There's very little involved.